# Are x64 build configurations supported for Roslyn Analyzers?

Tags: c#, 64-bit, roslyn, analyzer, buildconfiguration

I'd like to add an analyzer to a solution that exclusively contains x64 projects, and the analyzer is only meant to be applied to projects of that solution. Can I have a x64 build configuration for my Analyzer?

If I try that, the Analyzer compiles with x64, but when I try to add the Analyzer to a x64 project, I get IntelliSense warning CS8034 of category Roslyn.HostError:

> Unable to load Analyzer assembly C:...\TestAnalyzer.dll: Could not
>   load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users...\TestAnalyzer.dll' or one
>   of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

Adding the same analyzer when it is compiled with x86 works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roslyn doesn't care about the bitness of your analyzers; it just loads .Net assemblies.

However, Visual Studio itself is an x86 process.

If you make an x64-only analyzer, it will run perfectly fine from the Roslyn command line, but VS won't be able to load it.

---

Note that analyzer bitness has nothing to do with project bitness; analyzers are loaded into the compiler, not at runtime.